# Add Paypal to simple website

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Our Company</title>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main">
    <h1>E-commerce Website</h1> 
    <h2>Website Pages:</h2>

    <p>Home Page</p>
    <p>About Us</p>
    <p>Our Products</p>
    <p>Buy Now</p>
    <footer id="foot01"></footer>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="Email">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

</html>
```

It is a very simple HTML page, I am trying to add a code I've got from a paypal website on how to add a paypal button and (They said it should work when I add it to my Page) It is not working though...The form tag is flagging red error ??

Thanks for any Help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the HTML content to be displayed needs to be between the

```
<body>
```

and

```
</body>
```

tags.  Just move the Paypal content above the closing `</body>`.

Comment: I tried that and I still got error, attribute "border" is not allowed on element "input"

Comment: The border attribute is no longer used.  It won't stop a web browser displaying the button however.  You could replace it with CSS, see something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_border.asp).  However if that's the current HTML Paypal are giving you, personally I would just use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Your right its not supported in HTML5.. I figured how to do it.. Cheers :D